# Using OR, AND operator in single query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to list the records which meets my condition. As ii am using `AND` and `OR` operator together i am not getting the exact report. Here is my query

`SELECT o.sales_order_id AS SID, o.reference, o.status, o.last_modified, sol.sales_order_id, sol.item, sol.quantity, sol.selling_price, sol.discount, sol.tax, SUM(sol.tax_amount) AS Tamt, SUM(sol.total) as Total, i.iid, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.name) AS iname, l.company, t.tax_id, t.name as tname, t.rate from orders o INNER JOIN before_order_line_items sol ON o.sales_order_id = sol.sales_order_id INNER JOIN leads l ON o.company_id=l.id INNER JOIN items i ON sol.item=i.iid INNER JOIN taxes t ON sol.tax=t.tax_id WHERE o.order_quote='Order' AND o.authorise='Yes' OR o.assigned_to=6 OR o.user_id=6 GROUP BY o.sales_order_id ORDER BY o.sales_order_id DESC`

I am storing both orders and quotations in single table `Orders`, for orders i store it as `Order` in order_quote column, for Quotations it is `Quote`

It is not checking `order_quote='Order'` condition, it displays both orders and quotations.

if i remove  `OR o.assigned_to=6 OR o.user_id=6` , it gives proper result.

I tried using DISTINCT like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.order_quote=`Order`, .....
```

But does't work.

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT o.sales_order_id AS SID, o.reference, o.status, o.last_modified, sol.sales_order_id, sol.item, sol.quantity, sol.selling_price, sol.discount, sol.tax, SUM(sol.tax_amount) AS Tamt, SUM(sol.total) as Total, i.iid, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.name) AS iname, l.company, t.tax_id, t.name as tname, t.rate from orders o INNER JOIN before_order_line_items sol ON o.sales_order_id = sol.sales_order_id INNER JOIN leads l ON o.company_id=l.id INNER JOIN items i ON sol.item=i.iid INNER JOIN taxes t ON sol.tax=t.tax_id WHERE (o.order_quote='Order' AND o.authorise='Yes') AND (o.assigned_to=6 OR o.user_id=6) GROUP BY o.sales_order_id ORDER BY o.sales_order_id DESC
```

Comment: add braces to your `AND` , `OR` condition, like `(o.authorise='Yes' OR o.assigned_to=6)`

Comment: not working sir

Comment: well, I didn't mean the exact condition. You need to add braces as per your logical condition as mentioned in below answer

Comment: i tried many possible ways. it is not working. Can i use DISTINCT

Comment: `DISTINCT` will only give distinct (unique) records. But if fulfill your requirement then you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parentheses.  I'm not sure exactly how, but your current `where` clause is interpreted as:

```
WHERE (o.order_quote = 'Order' AND o.authorise = 'Yes') OR
      (o.assigned_to = 6) OR
      (o.user_id = 6)
```

I would guess that you want something like this:

```
WHERE (o.order_quote = 'Order' AND o.authorise = 'Yes') AND
      (o.assigned_to = 6 OR o.user_id = 6)
```

But that is mere speculation.

Or perhaps:

```
WHERE (o.order_quote = 'Order' AND
      (o.authorise = 'Yes' OR o.assigned_to = 6 OR o.user_id = 6)
```

Comment: Yes, i want like this. But even if i use parenthesis as your 2nd statement, i get no result, empty result set . I have updated my query above

Comment: Not working for parenthesis `WHERE (o.order_quote = 'Order' AND
      (o.authorise = 'Yes' OR o.assigned_to = 6 OR o.user_id = 6)`